# Should the new-york and the new-york-state tags be merged? Is the latter the better of the two?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

The [new-york](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york) tag has 237 questions and starts from 2015. It's usage guideline is:

> Questions concerning the laws, criminal justice system, civil court procedures and related topics **specific to the state of New York.** For questions pertaining only to the city use the "new-york-city" tag.

The [new-york-state](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york-state) tag has only 1 question from 2020 and seems to fall under the same scope.

People from New York City often think of "New York" as the city, and may tend to add "State" to distinguish the state from the city. "I'm from New York" doesn't create the impression that someone could be from Schenectady for example.

**Question:** I wonder the two tags should be merged, and if new-york-state is the better choice for the final tag?

---

fyi [new-york-city](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york-city) has 42 questions and also dates from 2015.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes and yes and its done

Comment: goodness... speedy!